# Calculate difference between 1 and 5 year intervals in a value column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a simple table containing only a few thousand records where the performance is not a major consideration.

I want to calculate the difference between values in the same column over `1` and `5` year intervals rolling down the list.

For example, let's say I have a table like this:

```
Name, Year, Value<br>

Joe       2014       25<br>
Joe       2013       22<br>
Joe       2012       26<br>
Joe       2011       18<br>
Joe       2010       21<br>
Mark      2014       33<br>
Mark      2013       31<br>
Mark      2012       34<br>
Mark      2011       28<br>
Mark      2010       18<br>
```

and it goes back years.

I want to add two columns for `1 year change` and `5 year change` on a running difference for a given name.

So the finished output would look like this (if possible):

```
Name, Year, Value, 1-yr-change, 5-yr-change<br>
Joe       2014       25           3               4<br>
Joe       2013       22           -4              <whatever 2013-2009 is><br>
Joe       2012       26           8           <br>    
Joe       2011       18           -3<br>
Joe       2010       21           <whatever 2010-2009 is><br>
Mark      2014       33           2               15<br>
Mark      2013       31           -3              <whatever 2013-2009 is><br>
Mark      2012       34           6<br>
Mark      2011       28           10<br>
Mark      2010       18           <whatever 2010-2009 is><br>
```

Here's what I attempted using the actual columns from my table:

```
select t1.Agency, t1.FY, t1.[Tax Appropriations],<br>
case when t2.FY = T1.FY - 1 then T1.[Tax Appropriations] - T2.[Tax Appropriations] else null end as '1-yr-change',<br>
case when t2.FY = T1.FY - 5 then T1.[Tax Appropriations] - T2.[Tax Appropriations] else null end as '5-yr-change'<br>
from dbo.SHEFMain as t1<br>
left JOIN dbo.SHEFMain as t2 on T1.Agency = T2.Agency and T2.FY < T1.FY<br>
order by agency, fy desc<br>
```

The calculations that resulted worked, but there's a lot of extra repeating rows with null values as well - so I obviously misunderstood the join process or something like that.

Comment: I see you already answered your own questions but fyi you probably could have salvaged your original query by changing the `T2.FY < T1.FY` to `T2.FY in (T1.FY-1, T1.FY-5)` with a `GROUP BY agency` and some appropriate aggregations on your columns. You weren't too far off!

Comment: Thanks WorkSmarter for the edits and shawnt00 for the efficiency suggestion - sorry I didn't read how to correctly format my first post here before posting it!

Answer (score 0):

I was given the answer on another forum - thanks for your help!  Here's what I was given and it seems to work perfectly.  Please let me know if you have any comments or concerns:

```
select t1.Agency
     , t1.FY
     , t1.[Tax Appropriations]
     , t1.[Tax Appropriations] - (SELECT T2.[Tax Appropriations] 
                             FROM dbo.SHEFMain as t2 
                             WHERE T2.Agency = T1.Agency 
                             AND T2.FY = T1.FY-1) as '1-yr-change'
     , t1.[Tax Appropriations] - (SELECT T3.[Tax Appropriations] 
                             FROM dbo.SHEFMain as t3 
                             WHERE t3.Agency = T1.Agency 
                             AND T3.FY = T1.FY-5) as '5-yr-change'
from dbo.SHEFMain as t1
order by T1.agency, 
         T1.fy DESC
```